# Using Parse after Installing Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform

If I follow the directions and install the Parse server via Heroku and MongoDB, will I then be able to continue to use Parse commands in my code for current and new apps?

That is, will following these instructions allow me to continue using Parse for in-app purchases, data storage, and push notifications, or will I still have to learn the ins and outs of a different backend service?

Thanks,

Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set up the Parse Server via Heroku and MongoDB, you will be able to use most of your current code, with some slight modifications. In your client apps, you will have to point to the new server location in the Parse initialization.

As of right now, Parse server does not support in-app purchase verification, as far as I know. Right now it supports:

- CRUD operations
- Schema validation
- Pointers
- Users, including Facebook login and anonymous users
- Files
- Push Notifications
- Installations
- Sessions
- Geopoints
- Roles
- Class-level Permissions

More information is available at the [Official GitHub for Parse-Server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) including setup instructions and a quick setup button for Heroku